# "Program ended with exit code: 13" in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

What could this message: "Program ended with exit code: 13" mean in Xcode debug console and how to catch that? I have this message in Xcode console window randomly and I can't find any way to catch this under the debugger. Is there any way to set a breakpoint on this kind of program exit? My app is recording a video and running a http server while this is happening. However I do not see anything that could cause this in my code or in code from third party libraries. It seems to happen randomly and it does not show any other errors. I tried setting exception breakpoints, runtime issue breakpoints etc. but they do not catch anything. Any suggestions on how to find/debug what might causing this are welcome.

Comment: Have a look at the code that is saving the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the error was caused by http server and code 13 was related to SIGPIPE error during network communication. After adding:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
```

before starting the http server the problem disappeared.